# Multiple Spinner elements?

Tags: jquery, spinner, themeroller

I want to have spinner elements on my shopping cart to select quantity. Like this one:
http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

The problem is the spinner layout is applied to a input field with id="spinner", but how can I have multiple input fields, one for each product?

Doing this only the first field will have spinner layout:

```
<form action="shopping:cart.php" >
quantity 1: <input  id="spinner"><br>
quantity 2: <input  id="spinner"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate `id` attributes as it means the HTML of the page is invalid, and causes problems in JS.

Use a class to group instead:

```
<form action="shopping:cart.php" >
    quantity 1: <input class="spinner"><br>
    quantity 2: <input class="spinner"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you need to change your jQuery selector to recognise this class:

```
$('.spinner').spinner();
```